# Terminal on Mac does not save preferences

Tags: mac, terminal

I am using Mac High Sierra v10.13.1. I have been trying to save the preferences for terminal to something other than the default.

The strange thing is that whenever the terminal is closed (via command+Q) and after restarting, it will load back to the default profile. Even if I add a custom profile, the said profile will be gone. I am using Spotlight to launch the terminal (via command + space).

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Answer (score 12):

@justingiffard was correct with the chown command.

Shortest answer is:

1. Check the ownership of the terminal.plist by running
   `ls -l ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist`
2. If the ownership is `root` or something other than your username then the ownership needs to change to you. The usergroup may also need to change if it's not already `staff`. Both can be done with one command:
   `sudo chown <your username>:staff ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist`
3. You will be prompted to enter your password, and then you should be able to save your preferences once and for all! You can verify that step 2 worked by running the code in step 1 again to confirm that you are now listed as the owner

Comment: Verified this works on Catalina version 10.15.6

Comment: Thanks worked for me on 12.5.1. Disk Utility used to try and repair permissions like this but doesn't seem to any more.

Answer (score 3):

I found [this discussion on Apple Discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3219909?answerId=16641009022#16641009022) and much like a few other places they mention a fix that relates to `~/Library/Preferences/`. What they suggested was to delete the plist file for the specific package and then logout and log back in again.

I investigated this by saying `ls -l ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist` which showed me the following permisions: `-rw-------  1 root` for the file... ah getting somewhere!

I used `ls -l ~/Library/Preferences/` to see the permissions of the rest of the directory and most of the others were `-rw-------  1 justin`. Yup definitely onto something here.

I then moved that file to Desktop (`sudo mv ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist ~/Desktop`) instead of deleting it and then rebooted my machine and hey presto terminal was happy and saved my preferences and profile. Win!

I then once again checked permissions of files in `~/Library/Preferences/` and all of them except for `com.apple.Safari.plist` was owned by me. So I deleted that and deleted the Terminal plist from my desktop (`sudo rm ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist` and `sudo rm ~/Desktop/com.apple.Terminal.plist`) and rebooted

Now I am not 100% sure whether or not one could have fixed this with `chown`, maybe someone can try?
In my case it would be something like 
`sudo chown justin:staff ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist` 
or maybe even
`sudo chown -R justin:staff ~/Library/Preferences`

But deleting the plists did the trick for me also as a side note they also mention in that answer deleting `.lockfile`. I didnt have any so skipped that step.

Comment: Ultimately, the result of re-creating the `plist` file is the same as `chown` as you suggest, tried in [Microooooo's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1437836/187049); you become the owner of the preference list file so you can save your prefs.

Answer (score 3):

Terminal Shell -> Preferences -> Profile [Screenshot of the terminal Profiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PzVj.png)

Ensure before you close the screen you click the "Default" option so that this is saved for the future. This worked for me. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had this, in that it would not remember my history across windows. My workaround is to add:

`SHELL_SESSION_HISTORY=0`

to the start of `~/.bash_profile`

You might also want to check Terminal.app Preferences:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input. Unfortunately this does not work for me as well.